# why does output is blank when i write function to give output 1 if user_input is A

Tags: python-3.7

```
print('Welocme')

numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

user_input = input('Enter Text: ')

def sort():
    if user_input == 'A':
        return numbers[0]
```

i expect output 1, when user_input is A, but when i run the code it's not printing anything

Comment: There you are not printing anything, also, you are not calling your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call your function after reading the input. Return wont do any print job so you have to print your result

```
print('Welocme')

def sort():
    if user_input == 'A':
        print(numbers[0])

numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

user_input = input('Enter Text: ')
sort()
```

Some important infos on using `return` in python [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-Python)